# toggle a checkbox attribute on a array of items in a carousel in Angular 2/Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this carousel. Each item in the carousel has a checkbox above it. I want to be able to click on item and the checkbox gets a checked attribute. The code does this. The only problem I'm having is it toggles all check boxes in the carousel. I just want it to toggle the one clicked.

```
      <tshq-carousel [dataSource]="brands" [selections]="selectedBrands"  (select)="onItemsSelected($event)" [changeKey]="changeKey" [pageSize]="5" [circular]="false"
    [enableSelection]="true"  mode="single">
    <ng-template let-brand>
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="brand.icon&&brand.icon.length>0">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="true" >
          <label class="apply carousel-checkbox">
          <input  type="checkbox" id="brandCheck" [checked]="isChecked" value="no" name = "brand">
          </label>
          <img [src]="formatLogo(brand.icon)" style="max-width:150px" (click)="isChecked = !isChecked" />
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>

  </tshq-carousel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `isChecked` variable to binding to all input checkbox of carousel, so when you change value (check or uncheck) 1 input checkbox, it also set to all remain ones.

I suggest you add 1 property to model `brand` and use it to binding to input checkbox or image. 
Ex:

```
<tshq-carousel [dataSource]="brands" [selections]="selectedBrands"  (select)="onItemsSelected($event)" [changeKey]="changeKey" [pageSize]="5" [circular]="false"
    [enableSelection]="true"  mode="single">
    <ng-template let-brand>
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="brand.icon && brand.icon.length>0">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="true" >
          <label class="apply carousel-checkbox">
          <input  type="checkbox" id="brandCheck" [checked]="brand.isChecked" value="no" name="brand">
          </label>
          <img [src]="formatLogo(brand.icon)" style="max-width:150px" (click)="brand.isChecked = !brand.isChecked" />
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>

  </tshq-carousel>
```